# Call function from a dynamically created Contract

Tags: solidity, transactions

I'm creating a `Main` contract which will be used to create dynamic contracts with `msg.sender` as `Owner`. Anyone can send `ETH` externally to the dynamic contract and anyone can withdraw `ETH` from the dynamic contract but it will only goto `Owner`.

**main.sol**

```
contract Main{
   // this contract will just create contracts
   mapping(address => address[]) public dynamic_contracts;
   function createContract(){
      address newContract = new Dynamic(msg.sender);
      dynamic_contracts[msg.sender].push(newContract);
   }
}
```

**dynamic.sol**

```
Contract Dynamic{
 // this contract will hold funds and transfer em
    address Owner;
    function Dynamic (address owner) {
        Owner = owner;
    } 
    function transferFunds(){
      //transfer it to Owner
      Owner.transfer(this.balance())
    }
}
```

The problem is `Dynamic` contract is created dynamically therefore i only have its address stored in mapping `dynamic_contracts` of `Main`. I don have its abi so how do i call `transferFunds` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dynamic = Dynamic(msg.sender);

Dynamic.transferFunds();
```